# How to apply array of images to a template helper in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, handlebars.js

I currently am trying to apply an array of images to my template HTML.

```
var z = [...jpg,...,jpg,...jpg];
var x = ["text","text","text"];
```

These arrays are stored globally in my file.

Here is my template helper function and I'm just using a sample index to see if it would be display in the HTML but it isn't working properly.

```
Template.stop.helpers({
    'thumb': function(){
      return  z[1];
    },
    'snippet': function(){
        return x[1];
    }
});
```

Here is my html template reference

```
 <template name="stop">  
      <tr>
        <td class="image"><img src="{{thumb}}"></td>
        <td>
         <center>    


    <h2> Do you like this product? </h2>
           <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style=" font-size: 50px; font-size=50px; margin-top: 50; padding-top: 5px;"></i>
           <h3>{{title}}</h3>
           <h2>{{snippet}}</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
```

and here is where it's referenced in a div in my body

```
<div class="bottom">
  {{> stop}}
  </div>
```

I want these images displayed in a table in my HTML but I'm not even able to display one. Any ideas?

Comment: if you do this what you get? `'thumb': function(){ console.log(z[1]) return  z[1];}` on the console.log?

Answer (score 1):

Code seems ok remove `var` keyword, maybe a duplicated on z x2?

```
 z = [...jpg,...,jpg,...jpg];
 x = ["text","text","text"];
```

if you have that array of images pointing to a `/public` folder add it also.

```
<td class="image"><img src="public/{{thumb}}"></td>
```

**update**

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
      z = [...jpg,...,jpg,...jpg];
      x = ["text","text","text"];
for(var i=0;i<z.length;i++){
   console.log(z[i])
 }
  Template.stop.helpers({
    'thumb': function(){
      console.log(z[1];
      return  z[1];
    },
    'snippet': function(){
        return x[1];
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Hi there I fixed the var issue however that was only a mistake on this , not actually in my code. The images point to image urls on Twitter.

Comment: if you put a console.log inside the template helper what did you get? console.log(z[1])?

Comment: It doesn't seem to print out anything at all even a line break with it. I've also tried to log it outside those template functions but it doesnt seem to print out anywhere in the if (Meteor.isClient)  only in the if (Meteor.isServer) but I can't declare those template function in the (Meteor.isServer) can I?

Comment: remove the var keyword just declare it like this check answer update

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue or not but those two arrays are declared globally in the file.  And then filled with information from a twitter api in a meteorIsServer section so can I still redeclare the arrays in the way you suggested? Or would i lose the information that way

Comment: i just want to be sure that `{{thumb}}` helpers its actually a acceptable path

Comment: Yeah I've tested it with returning plain text and it comes up as a broken image but it is proved that it is an acceptable working path.

Comment: at the end the helper should only return an string, and thats not happening, if you say that you put plaint text and you get a broken url, so there should be 1 reason for this. the arrays isn't returning a valid String (url)

Comment: After many console.logs its clear to me now that the global array z  with information put in  (Meteor.isServer)  isn't accessible inside (Meteor.isClient) , would I be right in saying the middle ground between these two states would be a mongoDB collection that contains that array information?

Comment: I dont get you, if you put that array variable inside the /lib folder it will be accesible both client/server

Comment: Sorry for the late response , what I meant to say was that the templates are loaded first before the z array is filled with information via Twitter API  on the server side so that's why it is returning as undefined. Would you know how to wait until the server side is finished before these template helpers load?

Comment: put the api code into a `Meteor.startup` or the array variables into a `tracker autorun`